# In Liferay, how do you change/add a preference for an OOTB portlet

Tags: liferay-6

I want to add the following portlet preference to the Asset Publisher portlet:

```
<preference>
    <name>assetLinkBehavior</name>
    <value>viewInPortlet</value>
</preference>
```

This should default the configuration so that when the user clicks on the title link of a shown asset, it will go directly to that asset in its context (view in context). This is a configuration in the portlet wrench configuration UI. But this is not the default behavior when I first add the Asset Publisher portlet. So I want to add this preference somewhere. Should it be in one of the xml files in a hook?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to override default portlet-custom.xml and provide preferences for asset-publisher

portlet [portlet-name 101] like

```
<portlet-preferences>
    <preference>
        <name>name</name>
        <value>value</value>
    </preference>
</portlet-preferences>
```

HTH